# Orocrm Azure VM https settings

Tags: azure, nginx, orocrm

I have deployed Orocrm image by Oro Inc in Azure from the marketplace.

The site works well with plain http.

Out of the box, /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf has only http settings.
I have added some sections for https server based on Oro's document
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/community-edition/#configure-web-server

and uploaded my certs. When I browse the site it downloads a file instead of serving the home page. What do I need to do to fix this? Adding everything in the sample configurations from the link above throws lots of errors.

EDIT:

I followed this documentation and I got it to work.
https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/setup/dev-environment/web-server-config/

Though, anytime I click somewhere inside the site, it switches back to http.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me:

I added this code inside the server {} block in default.conf

```
  if ($scheme = "http") {
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I have fixed the issue with

return 301 https://mydomain;

which redirects all http traffic to https.

Problem is, browser is not serving pages (too_many_redirects

Comment: After switching from HTTP to HTTPS, you have to login to the admin/ part to change the application URL config and website URL to use https everywhere. After that you will have to clear the browser cookie as HTTP cookies are not compatible with HTTPS in ORO, this might lead infinite redirects issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup balancer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-overview .
Then you should add echo "fastcgi_param HTTPS on;" >> "/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params"
And set https in application settings.